# PHPExcel. Displays more worksheets than available in .xlsx

Tags: php, loops, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel classes, and I notice that the web browser is displaying more work sheets than I have in the Excel file (Open the file with excel to check). One of the work sheets is deleted, but, it is displayed on the browser.
please help.

I am looping through the whole document (Excel file) and stopping at the end of each worksheet.

php Version 7.0.28
PHPExcel 1.8.0
Excel (office 2013 package)

if there is an alternative to "PHPExcel" that does not require stuff like "composer" to work. please let me know.

Comment: Need more info. Some part of code, How you have processed the sheets or reading it.

Comment: @Giri Annamalai M           `//LOAD FILE $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('Sample.xls');                                      //set active sheet to first sheet
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// sheets
$CurrentWorkSheetIndex = 0;
foreach ($excel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
//display sheets}`

Comment: Sample.xls should be Sample.xlsx

Comment: @Giri Annamalai M tried changing the file format to see if it will work. I get the same results. saved it first as xlsx, then I saved it as xls now as you can see

Comment: PHPExcel_IOFactory its old library. Can you try it with 
http://
phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io

Comment: Composer isn't required to make PHPExcel work, it's required to install it, as with most modern PHP libraries